# Django (DRF) not showing CORS POST-ed data (from React frontend)

Tags: python, django, cors

I am using a React frontend, communicating with a DRF (Django Rest Framework) backend.

Currently both are running on their own development server, so they are running on separate domains.

I am sending data from the frontend to the backend, using the POST method, using Axios to send the request.

The code I use can be seen below.

**The problem:**

Django doesn't seem to be receiving the POST-ed data.

As you can see in the code below, I try to print out the received data, but this is what I see in the console:

```
[12/Jun/2018 13:33:17] "OPTIONS /order/create HTTP/1.1" 200 0

request.POST:

<QueryDict: {}>

[12/Jun/2018 13:55:47] "POST /order/create HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

(it seems to be normal that the printed information comes first in the console, and the line for that POST request after that. Even though the print statement is executed by the POST request, not by the OPTIONS request. This confused me a bit initially.)

What I have tried already:

I've tried to add the following header:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

I've tried adding:

```
withCredentials: true
```

(commented out in my code, at the bottom if this post)

Initially this gave me an error about the response to the preflight request not containing an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header with the value of 'true'. And this error I resolved by adding the following:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

(from the django-cors-headers Django app, set this in settings.py) https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

and then manually adding the header to my response:

```
response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
```

I have already researched parts about CORS before, but again I have read the page below. It doesn't seem to give an answer.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

The axios code:

```
checkoutCart: function(submittedValues, products) {

  console.log("checkoutCart")

  console.log(submittedValues)

  console.log(products)

  // let data = {

  //   formData: submittedValues,

  //   productData: products,

  // }

  return axios({

    method: 'post',

    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/order/create',

    data: {

      formData: submittedValues,

      productData: products,

    },

    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},

    //withCredentials: true,

  })

    .then(function(response) {

      console.log(response)

    })

    .catch(function(error) {

      console.log("error", error)

    })

}
```

The Django view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from django.http import JsonResponse



@csrf_exempt

def handle_order(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print("request.POST:")

        print(request.POST)

    response = JsonResponse({})

    response['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'

    return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the post data with:

`request.body`

After you fetch the post data you need to decode it with

`request.body.decode('utf-8')`

If you wish to parse this dict of data you can use the `json` library to convert the string into a iterable dict using:

`json.loads(your_post_data)`

Heres an entire working snippet:

```
def handle_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        unparsed_json = request.body.decode('utf-8') #Get the data and decode it
        postData = loads(unparsed_json) #Convert it to [dict]
        for keys in postData:
            print(keys) #print all the values in the dict
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I will try that. I just read about request.post and request.body in the Django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/

Comment: No problem, I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for.